# Include with Entityframework + MySql don't work

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq

**I'm using Entity Framework 6.0.0.0 with MySQL Data Provider 6.9.9.0.**

When I search some information with *lambda/Linq*, the object `SOME_CLASS` is filled. but the `Include` doesn't work, in my context i'm using:

```
this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;

public partial class LOCAL_EVENTO_COLABORADOR
{
    public LOCAL_EVENTO_COLABORADOR()
    { 
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; } 
    public string id_local_evento { get; set; } 
    public virtual LOCAL_EVENTO LOCAL_EVENTO { get; set; }
```

}
    public void execute(){

```
using (BuffetContext db = new BuffetContext())
{
                var result = db.LOCAL_EVENTO_COLABORADOR.Include(l => l.LOCAL_EVENTO).ToList();


}
}
```

Script generate:

```
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.LOCAL_EVENTO_COLABORADOR",
            c => new
            { 
                id = c.String(unicode: false),
                nome = c.String(unicode: false), 0), 
                id_local_evento = c.String(unicode: false), 0), 
                LOCAL_EVENTO_id = c.Int(),
                LOCAL_EVENTO_COLABORADOR_NOTIFICACAO_id = c.Int(),
            })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.EMPRESAs", t => t.EMPRESA_id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.LOCAL_EVENTO", t => t.LOCAL_EVENTO_id) 
            .Index(t => t.LOCAL_EVENTO_id)
```

)

```
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.LOCAL_EVENTO",
            c => new
            {  
                top_menu_imagem = c.String(unicode: false),
                url_site = c.String(unicode: false),
                reenviar_proposta = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                EMPRESA_id = c.Int(),
                ENDERECO_id = c.Int(),
            })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.EMPRESAs", t => t.EMPRESA_id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.ENDERECOes", t => t.ENDERECO_id)
            .Index(t => t.EMPRESA_id)
            .Index(t => t.ENDERECO_id);
```

My Schema:

[image: it has Foreign key]

why itens.LOCAL_EVENTO has null?

Comment: does this help?    `var itens = db.SOME_CLASS.Include(d => d.ANOTHER_CLASS).ToList()`?

Comment: Have you checked the generated SQL? Your code looks "kind of" correct to me (kind of, since you are using `db.SOME_CLASS` while it should be `db.IDbSetPropertyOfSOME_CLASS` but since this is example code I hope that part is not what's wrong

Comment: to using .ToList() don't work